# Two column responsive layout where columns are specified in JSX

Tags: css, jsx

I've created this responsive layout but I'm unhappy with the implementation as it uses JavaScript. For various reasons I want a pure CSS solution, the main one is I want to animate them.

Here's the JSX and screenshots of the responsive behaviour that I'm looking for. Basically I want to know which CSS to apply to `SplitContent`, `SplitContentLeft`, and `SplitContentRight` to achieve this effect.

```
<SplitContent>
  <SplitContentLeft>First</SplitContentLeft>
  <SplitContentRight>Second</SplitContentRight>
  <SplitContentRight>Third</SplitContentRight>
  <SplitContentLeft>Fourth</SplitContentLeft>
  <SplitContentLeft>Fifth</SplitContentLeft>
</SplitContent>
```

Mobile layout

[image]

Desktop layout

[image: desktop layout]

EDIT:

Since people have asked, here's the implementation that uses TypeScript to sort the elements into their own arrays. The child components are just unstyled divs.

```
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";
import React from "react";
import { SplitContentLeft } from "./SplitContentLeft";
import { SplitContentRight } from "./SplitContentRight";

export type SplitContentProps = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div">;

export const SplitContent: React.FC<SplitContentProps> = ({
  className,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const leftChildren: React.ReactElement[] = [];
  const rightChildren: React.ReactElement[] = [];

  React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      if (child.type === SplitContentLeft) {
        leftChildren.push(child);
        return;
      }
      if (child.type === SplitContentRight) {
        rightChildren.push(child);
        return;
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <div
      className={twMerge("flex w-full gap-4 sm:gap-6", className)}
      {...props}
    >
      <div className={"flex w-full flex-col gap-4 sm:hidden"}>{children}</div>
      <div className={"hidden w-full flex-col gap-6 sm:flex sm:justify-center"}>
        {leftChildren}
      </div>
      <div className={"hidden w-full flex-col gap-6 sm:flex sm:justify-center"}>
        {rightChildren}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please consider providing the HTML and relevant CSS for the JSX components (if any), such that we can provide a solution for your particular situation.

Comment: Is there a rule for their orders?

Comment: This would be pretty simple with a CSS grid, how are you building your current layout?

Comment: @DBS Tried Grid for ages. Looks simple but really isn't.

Comment: @InSync The rule is that the item has to go in the column indicated by the JSX.

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle or something

Comment: Can the JSX change or it must remain intact?

Answer (score 0):

With CSS grid:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  /* Two columns by default */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /* Rows have the same width */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  /* Make blocks as dense as possible */
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

/* Mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #container div {
    /* Make them occupy both columns */
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  #container div {
    /* Span over two rows */
    grid-row-end: span 2;
  }
  .right {
    grid-column-start: 2;
  }
  #first-of-right {
    /* Right column starts at row 2 */
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
}
```

Try it:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #container div {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  #container div {
    grid-row-end: span 2;
  }
  .right {
    grid-column-start: 2;
  }
  /* :nth-child(1 of .right) */
  #first-of-right {
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
}


/* Demo only */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eff0ff;
  font-family: system-ui;
}

#container {
  padding: 1em;
  gap: 1em;
}

#container div {
  border: 1px solid #cecfe1;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>First</div>
  <div class="right" id="first-of-right">Second</div>
  <div class="right">Third</div>
  <div>Fourth</div>
  <div>Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Converting this to JSX should be trivial.